# Improve SQL Function That Searches Table For Matching String

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a function that searches a for a matching ICD-9 code in another table character by character. I am doing this because the format that we receive ICD-9 codes in is not consistent and many of them have extra numbers on the end or they may have a decimal in the wrong place or even missing.

We have no option other than looking for partial matches to at least find the category that the ICD9 falls in. We are not using this for billing purposes, so a partial match is okay. Luckily, ICD9 code are structured and numbered by category. So lets say that we receive a code for 'Lymphosarcoma Involving Intra Abdominal Lymph Node' which is 200.13. We may receive the code as 20013, 20.013, 200.13112, etc..., but I can match the code character by character until I find the closest match, which for all of the examples I provided would be 200.13.

The function works almost 100% correctly, it just takes a very long time to run because has to search the lookup table 4 or 5 times to look for the closest match, which makes the function really slow. Especially when it has to match up to 12 codes per record for 1000's of records.

Any ideas on improving the query?

```
/*  Find match for an ICD9 code in LookupDiseases and selects the desciption . Return the matching 
    description for the ICD9 code.
*/
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[uf_LookupICD9Desc] (@ClaimA99 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,@ICD9 NVARCHAR(10))  
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS  
BEGIN
DECLARE @Substring NVARCHAR (10)
DECLARE @Description NVARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @Length INT
DECLARE @Count INT

/* Remove decimal place from string */
SET @ICD9 = REPLACE(@ICD9,'.','')

/* Get lenth of string */
SET @Length = LEN(@ICD9)

/* Initialize count */
SET @Count = 1

/* Get Substring */
SET @Substring = SUBSTRING(@ICD9,1,@Count)

/* Start processing */
IF (@Length < 1 OR @ICD9 IS NULL)
    /* Validate @ICD9 */
    BEGIN

        SET @Description = 'No match found for ICD-9.'

    END
ELSE IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LookupDiseases WHERE REPLACE(LookupCodeDesc,'.','') LIKE @Substring + '%') < 1)
    /* Check for at least one match */
    BEGIN

        SET @Description = 'No match found for ICD-9.'

    END
ELSE
    /* Look for matching code */
    BEGIN

        WHILE ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LookupDiseases WHERE REPLACE(LookupCodeDesc,'.','') LIKE @Substring + '%') <> 1 AND (@Count < @Length + 1))
        BEGIN

            /* Update substring value */
            SET @Substring = SUBSTRING(@ICD9,1,@Count + 1)

            /* Increment @Count */
            SET @Count += 1

            /* Select the first matching code and get description */
            SELECT TOP(1) @Description = LookupName FROM LookupDiseases WHERE REPLACE(LookupCodeDesc,'.','') LIKE @Substring + '%' ORDER BY LookupCodeDesc ASC

        END
    END

    /* Return the ICD9 code description.  */
    RETURN(@Description)
END
```

Comment: Does anyone know why SQL code will not show up correctly when posted? I am pasting it from SSMS.

Comment: I think you should prepend 4 spaces to all code lines..

Comment: What was your question?  Also, I don't see how you can remove decimals for an ICD9 code, they're crucial to determining the value.  Can you provide examples of your input and output?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question. I was frustrated trying to format the code and forgot.

Comment: Matt, with an automated system, you can say 200.13112 matches 200.13, but not that 20.013 matches 200.13.  Are you working with a limited set of codes, or do your vendors consistently misplace the decimal point?  Looking through the phone book of ICD9 codes shows that the decimal in different places means different things. What kinds of assumptions are you making about the input?

Answer (score 2):

*Any ideas on improving the query?*

Don't take responsibility for

*the format that we receive ICD-9 codes in is not consistent and many of them have extra numbers on the end or they may have a decimal in the wrong place or even missing*

Don't attempt to match ICD-9 codes character by character independent of the decimal position, just return the match using a join when there is one and return the codes that don't match and need to be resolved by a person with business knowledge.

If you need to match higher level codes, for example, 101.0 should match 101.01, 101.00, 101.009, etc., then you can either create a lookup table for the matches, if it's on a small scale, or, if not, store a marker in another field so you can limit the search by the length of the higher-level code.

---

Also, you need to search by stripping characters from the end of the code.  For example, if your input code is 200.13112 and that doesn't match anything you have, you next search for 200.1311, and then 200.131, where you find your match.

I understand codes are entered incorrectly, just don't agree it's your responsibility to determine what the medical provider 'should have' entered.

Comment: I agree that we should not be trying to compensate for the mistakes of the insurance company, but because of the nature of our business it is vital that we inspect insurance claims to find the ICD-9 category that a claim was for. We are working on a fairly large scale, nearly 7 million claims so any improvement in matching would be helpful.

Comment: If it's a bad entry, you need to reject it, but you need to make a distinction between an exact match, which you can search for quickly, and a higher-level match, which will take longer to find (you can strip one char at a time off the length of the code that doesn't match until you find one.)  The decimal should not be ignored or replaced, in my opinion.

Comment: The insurers that we are working with are quite large, but even they are unable to resolve the issue of the ICD9 being coded incorrectly because the codes are entered at the hospital/doctors office where the claim took place. So we are stuck with the format that we receive them in as bad as the data is.

Comment: Ok, your suggestion makes sense. Although I cannot reject bad codes I can possibly create a separate query to match the good ones and then go back through and match any bad ones. That should help some. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much control you have, but perhaps you can additionally store them as text without the decimal points and index that column, which would allow for quick 'LIKE' queries.  Conceivably you could do this as an indexed view or an indexed computed column.